# Raising concerns about dirty and unhygienic workplace

Tags: professionalism, work-environment, email, cleanliness

Yesterday I found food boxes and empty cups all around office creating what I consider to be a dirty and unhygienic workplace.

I'd like to raise this to my boss for them to address.

What is the best/most professional way to do this? I was thinking of doing so over e-mail, would this be appropriate and if so is there a best way to frame this?

Comment: I'm sorry, but how are you asking us to help?  Are you wanting to know how to frame up an email?  Your question is very terse and as it stands reads as a demand rather than a request which is highly likely to get it closed without an answer.

Comment: Yes i want to know how to form a professional email to explain this issue to my boss

Comment: You might not write an email, but speak face to face with your boss

Comment: I've edited your question to try and make it answerable here. Hopefully I haven't substantially changed your intent. If I have feel free to revert my edit and apply your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the best/most professional way to do this? I was thinking of doing so over e-mail, would this be appropriate and if so is there a best way to frame this?

I suggest a two step approach:

1. **Try asking your coworkers first about who left those things laying over the office**. You can then kindly remind them to be more considerate on future situations when they eat or drink in the office workplace. This will surely make them more aware the next time and clean before leaving.
2. **If no one comes up**, or well if they do but **continue to leave the office dirty** on future occasion, you can then proceed to **write an email to your boss** explaining your situation. On it you can explain the situation (I suggest you refrain from pointing fingers, just stick to the fact that it was dirty) and ask him to write a reminder to everyone about this problem.

This way you are being professional, as you are first giving them the chance to change before escalating, and if you do escalate you are doing it in a polite and constructive way. If they continue to disobey that request from your boss then that would be a loss to them, as they have already been officially warned.